# Nunittest of auto refill if WaterContainer

Tags: c#

I want to test if the water container is refilled when empty, below is my method's code:

```
//Tests if the water is refilled if empty.
public void RefillWaterContainerTest()
{
    Console.Write("Test the water refill");
    int EContainer = new WaterContainer();
    FillUpContainer();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, EContainer); 
}
```

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
public class WaterContainer : Container {
    public WaterContainer(int level) { Level = level; }
    public override void GetContent() { 
    if (HasContent()) {
            Level -= 1;
        } else {
            if (FillUpWater() == false) {
                throw new EmptyContainerException("No water.");
            } else {
                Level -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    protected bool FillUpWater() {
        WaterTap tap = new WaterTap();
        if (tap.FillUpContainer()) {
            Level = 5; return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} //And the water tap class: class WaterTap { public bool FillUpContainer() { return true; } }
```

Comment: Cool. What is your question? Because if it's "How do I test if the water container is refilled", sorry to disappoint you, but nobody knows your attributes and data structures, so nobody can help you...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes... I figured :-) The website says that the code is too long, i'll try in an comment...

Comment: the rest of the code likes as followes: public class WaterContainer : Container
    {
        public WaterContainer(int level)
        {
            Level = level;
        }

        public override void GetContent()
        {
            if (HasContent())
            {
                Level -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (FillUpWater() == false)
                {
                    throw new EmptyContainerException("No water.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Level -= 1;

Comment: & the water tap method:        protected bool FillUpWater()
        {
            WaterTap tap = new WaterTap();

            if (tap.FillUpContainer())
            {
                Level = 5;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } //And the water tap class: class WaterTap
    {

        public bool FillUpContainer()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

Comment: `int EContainer = new WaterContainer();` doesn't look right to me... And please don't post your code in the comments, add it to the question.

Comment: @RaniIt: Please *don't* put code in comments that belongs in the question. Noone is going to read the resulting unformatted mess, anyway! If the website tells you that your code blocks are too long, then don't just evade that warning; instead, please try to condense the code into something shorter, more terse. Chances are that we don't actually need to know *all* the details.

Answer (score 0):

If WaterTap.FillUpContainer always returns true, then FillUpWater will never return false, which means that you never throw the EmptyContainerException, making any Tests rather pointless. I suggest fixing that first.

After that you can check if the exception is thrown by using [Assert.Throws](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5).

```
Assert.Throws(EmptyContainerException,FillUpContainer);
```